# Safely unbind statefulset/my-pod-0 pvc without affecting the other replicas

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-statefulset, kubernetes-pvc

I have a statefulset with 2 pods, running on separate dedicated nodes, each with its own pvc.

I need to perform some maintenance to the PVs assigned to each of the PVCs assigned to the statefulset's pods.

So far I've been able to scale down the statefulset to 1 replica, which brought offline statefulset/pod-1, this way I've been able to perform the maintenance task.

Now I need to perform the same task to statefulset/pod-0, without taking offline statefulset/pod-1.

What are my options?
Remember, statefulset/pod-0's pv must be unmounted in order to start the maintenance task.

Comment: what task do you want to perform on your PVC that requires it to be unbound?

Comment: @OlGe i need to move the cinder pv from one backend to another, I corrected the question, I need it to be unmounted not unbound

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to perform the task on statefulset/pod-0 by:

- Cordon the node
- Delete statefulset/pod-0

Once the task was complete uncordon the node and the pod started automatically without any issues.

This will only work if the pod contains a specific nodeAffinity

Comment: creative solution! nice!

Comment: It didn't work for my situation but thats really a good idea

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that this is possible to achieve with one statefulset because of the [Deployment and Scaling Guarantees](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/#deployment-and-scaling-guarantees) a statefulset provides. To unmount the volume of a pod, you must shutdown/delete the pod first and before this can be done to a pod in a statefulset, "all of its successors must be completely shutdown."

My advice is to plan and communicate a maintenance window with the stakeholders of the application and scale down the statefulset entirely to apply the changes to the volume in your storage backends. Moving volumes across storage backends is not a task to perform on a regular basis, so I think it is reasonable to ask for a one-time maintenance to do so.

Comment: It would be nice if Kubernetes offered a way to down scale the replicas starting from pod-0 up to pod-N

Answer (score 1):

`...to move the cinder pv from one backend to another`

With Cinder CSI you can perform a [snapshot](https://github.com/kubernetes/cloud-provider-openstack/blob/master/docs/cinder-csi-plugin/examples.md#snapshot-create-and-restore) or [clone](https://github.com/kubernetes/cloud-provider-openstack/tree/master/examples/cinder-csi-plugin/clone) the volume into a new PV and move to another.

Comment: Would I need to shut down statefulset/pod-0 prior to the clone operation?